# SlickGrid which uses SlickDataView does not render any data

Tags: javascript, typescript, slickgrid

I'm trying to implement a column filter within a SlickGrid.  I'm leveraging concepts from [this header row sample](https://6pac.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example-header-row.html) (the sample itself might be a bit out of date since it's still using the *Slick.Grid* notation, but this was the closest I could find).  When the grid simply uses the raw data, the data will render just fine in the grid.  However, when I try to use the SlickDataView object, then data no longer shows up in the grid.  Here are some code extracts:

```
import { Column, DataViewOption, SlickDataView, SlickGrid } from 'slickgrid';
```

The following code loads the grid, the line which creates the grid object will work when using *testData*, but fails when using *dataView*.

```
var gridOptions = {
    enableCellNavigation: true,
    enableColumnReorder: false,
    showHeaderRow: true,
    headerRowHeight: 30,
    explicitInitialization: true
};
var dataViewOption: DataViewOption = {
    groupItemMetadataProvider: null,
    inlineFilters: false
}
var columns = [];
var columnFilters = [];

var dataView = new SlickDataView(dataViewOption);

//the following line works:
var testGrid = new SlickGrid('#testGrid', testData, this.getColumns(), gridOptions);
//the following line fails:
//var testGrid = new SlickGrid('#testGrid', dataView, this.getColumns(), gridOptions);

testGrid.init();
dataView.beginUpdate();
dataView.setItems(testData);
dataView.endUpdate();
```

Comment: don't call `testGrid.init()` when using SlickDataView and with the option you have I think you should simply call it without any options, also your columns must be ready before you instantiate SlickGrid and it's not clear if they are in your code sample. There are plenty of demo with the DataView, you should take a look at all the [Examples](https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid/wiki/Examples) available